# Is there a way to modify a Docker builder image to include a custom CA?

Tags: docker, ssl, ca, buildx

I am running a Docker BuildX bake job in a company network which uses custom CAs. Initially, this posed a challenge because the builder instance has to be set up specifically to allow using local mirrors and the company CA. Regular configuration options of the builder like shown below did the trick there.

Next task is to allow the actual Dockerfile to retrieve content from HTTPS URIs which are also using custom CAs for the TLS setup. Specifically, the Dockerfile is using an `ADD https://... /target/path` statement like shown below which works well in a regular Docker build command.

But BuildX jobs run inside a Docker container that I seem to be unable to influence. If the build is run there, the output is something like this:

```
#8 [bare] https://internal-site.company.int/bucket/important-artifact.gpg
#8 ERROR: Get "https://internal-site.company.int/bucket/important-artifact.gpg": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

------
 > [bare] https://internal-site.company.int/bucket/important-artifact.gpg:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to load cache key: Get "https://internal-site.company.int/bucket/important-artifact.gpg": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Which is totally understandable because the image used seems to be `moby/buildkit` and that of course has no knowledge of my custom CA. The builder configuration only tells the Docker daemon to use a specific CA for the registry contact, not for all other HTTPS activity.

This is my TOML for the Builder:

```
[registry."docker.io"]
  mirrors = ["dockermirror.company.int"]
[registry."dockermirror.company.int"]
  ca = ["/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem"]
```

This is my Dockerfile (an abbreviated form of it):

```
FROM centos:8.3.2011 as bare

ADD https://internal-site.company.int/bucket/important-artifact.gpg /var/lib/company/key.gpg
```

I have searched with no avail for an option to tell the builder to

- either use an image of my liking which includes a custom CA
- let me execute a copy command or similar of my CA into the builder container during its creation

Does anybody know the trick and can point me into the right direction?